# VB.net: Input string not correct format?

Tags: vb.net, input

Hey guys I have been having this crashing problem with my program.

I am trying to create a program where it calculates a persons account balance by inputting their beginning balance, credit limit, total charges, and total credits. In this case I am having specific problems with the Total Charges and Total Credits Code.

I have a message box set up to where if the Total Charges and total credits box are blank it will say "please enter a numeric value for ....".  The problem is that when I do run it and enter a blank, the message shows up and then the program crashes.

After crashing, the The program then highlights in yellow the specific conversion code (in this case: `decTotalCharges = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalCharges.Text))` and the error says `Input string was not in correct format`.

What's going on, I converted it into a correct format right? (decimal to decimal?). Here's an in depth look at my code:

```
Public Class frmEndingBalance

'Declare module level variables
Dim mdecEndingBalance As Decimal
Dim mdecAllCharges As Decimal
Dim mdecAllCredits As Decimal
Dim mintCustomersOverLimit As Integer

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    'clears the form
    'clears the labels
    txtAccountNumber.Text = ""
    txtBeginningBalance.Text = ""
    txtTotalCharges.Text = ""
    txtTotalCredits.Text = ""
    txtCreditLimit.Text = ""
    lblEndingBalance.Text = ""
    lblCreditMessage.Text = ""
    lblAllCharges.Text = ""
    lblAllCredits.Text = ""
    lblCustomersOverLimit.Text = ""
    lblCreditMessage.Text = ""

    'clear the textboxes
    txtAccountNumber.Clear()
    txtBeginningBalance.Clear()
    txtTotalCredits.Clear()
    txtTotalCharges.Clear()
    txtCreditLimit.Clear()

    'clear module level variables
    mdecEndingBalance = 0
    mdecAllCharges = 0
    mdecAllCredits = 0
    mintCustomersOverLimit = 0
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    'Declare Variables
    Dim intAccountNumber As Integer
    Dim intBeginningBalance As Integer
    Dim decTotalCharges As Decimal
    Dim decTotalCredits As Decimal
    Dim decCreditLimit As Decimal
    Dim mdecEndingBalance As Decimal 'Beginning Balance + Charges - Credits()
    Dim decCreditMessage As Decimal

    'check for numeric
    If IsNumeric(txtAccountNumber.Text) = False Then 'value is not numeric
        MessageBox.Show("You can't enter anything blank!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'convert to a numeric data type
    intAccountNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtAccountNumber.Text)

    'check for numeric
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBeginningBalance.Text) Then MessageBox.Show("Beginning Balance Cannot Be Blank!")

    'check for everything else
    If IsNumeric(txtBeginningBalance.Text) = False Then 'Value is not numeric
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value for Beginning Balance!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'convert to a numeric data type
    intBeginningBalance = Convert.ToInt32(txtBeginningBalance.Text)

    'check for numeric
    If IsNumeric(txtTotalCharges.Text) = False Then 'value is not numeric
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value for Total Charges!")
    End If

    'convert 
    decTotalCharges = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalCharges.Text)

    'check for 0 or positive
    If decTotalCharges < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive value or zero for number of Total Charges!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'check for numeric
    If IsNumeric(txtTotalCredits.Text) = False Then 'value is not numeric 
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value for Total Credits")
    End If

    'convert to a numeric data type
    decTotalCredits = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalCredits.Text)


    'check for 0 or positive
    If decTotalCredits < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive value or zero for total credits!")
    End If

    'check numeric
    If IsNumeric(txtCreditLimit.Text) = False Then 'value is not numeric
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value for the Credit Limit!")
    End If

    'convert to a numeric data type
    decCreditLimit = Convert.ToDecimal(txtCreditLimit.Text)


    'check for a 0 or positive
    If decCreditLimit < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive value or zero for Credit Limit!")
    End If

    'check for customers over limit
    decCreditMessage = decCreditLimit - (mdecEndingBalance)

    'running totals
    mdecAllCharges += decTotalCharges
    mdecAllCredits += decTotalCredits

    'calculate Ending Balance
    mdecEndingBalance = Convert.ToDecimal(intBeginningBalance + decTotalCharges - (decTotalCredits))

    'display outputs
    lblEndingBalance.Text = mdecEndingBalance.ToString("c")
    lblAllCharges.Text = mdecAllCharges.ToString("c")
    lblAllCredits.Text = mdecAllCredits.ToString("c")
    lblCustomersOverLimit.Text = mintCustomersOverLimit.ToString("n0")
End Class
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Step through the code to see what the values are and where the code is going wrong. If your values are empty, then try `If Not IsNumeric(txtValue.Text) Then`

Comment: Please use paragraph breaks in your question. They break up the large wall of text and make it easier to read (which is why they were invented in the first place), and the easier it is to read and understand your question the better your chances are of getting an answer. :-) You can preview your question while entering it just below the text box in an almost WYSIWYG display, so you can check it's appearance.

Comment: you have to validate and if value is not empty and if it is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed Exit Sub out of the test

```
If IsNumeric(txtTotalCharges.Text) = False Then 'value is not numeric
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value for Total Charges!")
End If
```

You've done it in a few other places as well (as have we all , in fact as do we all :( ). Be worth refactoring with a little helper method or something similar.

```
If IsValidDecimal(txtTotalCharges.Text, "Total Charges") 
  ' etc
End If
```